# Creating a jQuery object inside an for loop of an array with class names

Tags: jquery, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to dynamically add classes when calling function and storing them in an array, then create jQuery objects for each item in array (will use it with .clone() further on). However the jQuery objects returns as undefined. What am I missing?

JS:

```
jQuery.fn.cloneInfo = function (myClasses) {
            $this = jQuery(this);
            myClassArray = [];


            var splitClasses = myClasses.split(' ');
            jQuery.each(splitClasses, function(){
                myClassArray.push(this);    
            });



            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < myClassArray.length; i++) {
                thisClass = myClassArray[i];
                alert(thisClass); //THIS RETURNS .my-class-1 & .my-class-2
                $thisClone = jQuery(thisClass);
                alert($thisClone.attr('class')); //THIS RETURNS UNDEFIENED
            }
        }

        jQuery('.wrap').on('click', '#button', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            $this = jQuery(this);
            jQuery(this).cloneInfo('.my-class-1 .my-class-2');

        });
```

Comment: Ok, found the fix:

change `$thisClone = jQuery(thisClass);` to `$thisClone = jQuery("" + thisClass);`

Comment: `"" + String` is pointless and shouldn't make any difference. Provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: `jQuery(this).cloneInfo('.my-class-1 my-class-2');`: The first selector has a dot and the second one doesn't.

Comment: @charlietfl Yet it did ... weird. And without that fix I get error message `uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined`

Comment: @JenniferGoncalves Yes, that was just a typo for the example (using a slightly different naming in my actual project)

Comment: So you are trying to find elements that has class "my-class-1" and "my-class-2"?

Comment: @CarlPapworth you are aware that jQuery does most of this in only about two 
 or three methods?

Comment: @zer00ne If I was aware of better methods I'd probably use them, please enlighten me :)

Comment: @CarlPapworth your question is vague on certain details so I guessed, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55421091/2813224)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially it appears these are the objectives:

1. Click a button:

   ```
   $('button').on('click', function() {...});
   ```
2. Add multiple classes to a given collection (in OP this part is vague)

   ```
   $(collection).addClass(cList)
   ```
3. Return an array (OP is not clear as to what this array consists of)

   ```
   $(collection).toArray()
   ```
4. So if all assumptions are correct:

   ```
   $('button').on('click', function() {
     var cArr = $(collection).addClass(cList).toArray();
     console.log(cArr)'
   });
   ```

The following demo is a reusable plugin of the code above. The plugin is wrapped in a click event handler instead of including an event handler in the plugin itself.

**Plugin......:** `.classArray()`
**Signature:**  `$(collection).classArray(cList);`
**Parameters**
    **collection**      [`String`]: Any valid selector
    **cList** [`DOMTokenString`]: A space delimited list of classNames
**Note:** The CSS is optional and not required.

```js
$.fn.classArray = function(cList) {
  this.addClass(cList);
  return this.toArray();
}

$('button').on('click', function() {
  var cArr = $('li, p, a').classArray('c1 c2');
  //var cArr = $('li, p, a').addClass('c1 c2').toArray();
  console.log(cArr);
});
```

```css
*:after {
  content: ' 'attr(class)
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 40%
}

.as-console-row.as-console-row::after {
  content: '';
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <button>classArray</button>
</header>
<main>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ol>
        <li><a href='#/'>LINK</a></li>
        <li><a href='#/'>LINK</a></li>
        <li><a href='#/'>LINK</a></li>
      </ol>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <article>
    <h1>MAIN TITLE</h1>
    <p>CONTENT</p>
  </article>
</main>
<footer></footer>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```